# Missing correlation id in response message with Spring and ActiveMQ

Tags: java, activemq-classic, spring-integration

I am learning Spring Integration with a very simple experiment. I have setup two queues in ActiveMQ, namely requestQueue and responseQueue. What I want to do is that a message is sent to the requestQueue and then the application will pick up and echo back to the responseQueue. Here is the configuration in integration.xml

```
<int:channel id="requestChannel"/>
<int:channel id="responseChannel"/>
<int:service-activator id="echoServiceActivator" input-channel="requestChannel" ref="echoServiceImpl"
                       requires-reply="true" output-channel="responseChannel"/>

<jms:inbound-gateway request-channel="requestChannel" reply-channel="responseChannel"
                     connection-factory="jmsConnectionFactory"
                     request-destination="requestQueue" default-reply-destination="responseQueue"
                     id="echoGateway" />
```

And the service class

```
@Service
public class EchoServiceImpl implements EchoService {

  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EchoServiceImpl.class);

  @Override
  @ServiceActivator
  public String echo(Message<String> message) {
    logger.info("Received message: {}", message.getPayload());
    return message.getPayload();
  }
}
```

Things go well with the content in the responseQueue. The problem is that the correlation-id never shows up. I expect that it will contain the message id of the request message. I have tried to put different value to correlation-key attribute of inbound-gateway but to no success. Is there something wrong or the inbound-gateway should not be used at the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Tha gateway correlation handling logic is [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-jms/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/jms/ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener.java#L392).

Pseudo code:

```
If the gateway has a `correlation-key`
    if the correlation key is `JMSCorrelationID`
        echo the inbound `message.JMSCorrelationID`
    else
        echo the inbound correlation key header
else
    if the inbound message has a `JMSCorrelationID`
        echo the inbound `message.JMSCorrelationID`
    else
        set the `reply.JMSCorrelationID` to the inbound `message.JMSMessageID`
```

Comment: Also `response-channel` is for waiting reply for gateway. The JMS reply (and therefore correlation) is done later